# How to delete files sent to Docker daemon build context

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I ran this command in my home directory:

```
docker build .
```

and it sent 20 GB files to the Docker daemon before I knew what was happening. I have no space left on my laptop. How do I delete the files that were replicated? I can't locate them.

Comment: Are you sure these files are replicated somewhere, besides any copies to the image? what if you restart the daemon?

Comment: Answers are good so far... unless you're on a mac... there is a problem reclaiming space there. If you want an answer for that, take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/UmkaDK/342fcbb32f69c71878a415c0ea8eee1e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the space is being used by the resulting image. Locate and delete it:

```
docker images
```

Search there by `size` column.

Then delete it:

```
docker rmi <image-id>
```

Also you can **delete everything** docker-related:

```
docker system prune -a
```

Answer (score 6):

What happens when you run `docker build .` command:

1. Docker client looks for a file named `Dockerfile` at the same directory where your command runs. If that file doesn't exists, an error is thrown.
2. Docker client looks a file named `.dockerignore`. If that file exists, Docker client uses that in next step. If not exists nothing happens.
3. Docker client makes a `tar` package called `build context`. Default, it includes everything in the same directory with `Dockerfile`. If there are some `ignore` rules in `.dockerignore` file, Docker client excludes those files specified in the `ignore` rules.
4. Docker client sends the `build context` to Docker engine which named as `Docker daemon` or `Docker server`.
5. Docker engine gets the `build context` on the fly and starts building the image, step by step defined in the `Dockerfile`.
6. After the image building is done, the `build context` is released.

So, your build context is not replicated anywhere but in the image you just created if only it needs all the build context. You can check image sizes by running this: `docker images`. If you see some unused or unnecessary images, use `docker rmi unusedImageName`.

If your image does'nt need everything in the build context, I suggest you to use `.dockerignore` rules, to reduce `build context` size. Exclude everything which are not necessary for the image. This way, the building process will be shorter and you will see if there is any misconfigured `COPY` or `ADD` steps in the `Dockerfile`.

For example, I use something like this:

```
# .dockerignore
* # exclude everything
!build/libs/*.jar # include just what I need in the image
```

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/

Comment: the image didn't complete building, I restarted the machine several times, but am still out of memory. How I can delete the `build context` ??

Comment: @JoeNyugoh did you add a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: no I didn't but now I understand the workflow of Docker.

Answer (score 2):

In case of stopping the building context for some reason, you can go as well to /var/lib/docker/tmp/, with **root access**, and then erase the tmp files of docker builder. In this situation, the building context doesn't build correctly, so the part that it did build, was saved in a tmp file in **/var/lib/docker/tmp/**